# Find latest object in hierarchy where the latest isn't marked as deleted

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables (of interest). The first table is a simple hierarchy. Each row has an ID, and a parent ID. Obviously, the parent ID can be NULL when we reach the top of that particular hierarchy. (We store multiple trees here, so there can be multiple NULL parents, but that's probably not important here.)

The second table has objects that have a non-unique identifier, for example a name, a timestamp, and a reference to the first table to indicate where on the hierarchy it sits.

Let's say the first table has a hierarchy of `/A/B/C`, and the second has a bunch of objects named "Foo".  If I'm trying to get the latest Foo in `/A/B`, then I don't want to get anything from C. This seems straightforward enough.  However, if the latest "Foo" in `/A/B` is marked in the database with a field saying it is deleted, e.g., `status = 'deleted'`, I want to instead get the latest "Foo" in `/A` even if there are other "Foo" objects with earlier timestamps in `/A/B`.

Is this possible to do in a CTE? Or do I have to resort to a stored procedure to get this type of logic? I'm already using some stored procedures just for refactoring purposes, so that's not a barrier, but if I can do this in a simpler manner that I'm missing, that may be better (including for performance).

Since that's probably a bit vague, I [put this on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/993b8/1/0). If I add in the override on line 24 of the schema, I should get that as the output. However, if I also add the deleted object in 26, I need to get back to the "update in /A" as the output.

Comment: Please check **[Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7b4d27e2f8282fe9b68316d7985346c0)** if it suits you I will post it as answer.

Comment: @lad2025 that seems to work with some extended testing, but I don't exactly follow how. I would be grateful if you not only posted it as an answer (so I could accept) but also with an explanation of the voodoo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extend your code with one intermediate step:

```
with recursive _rpath as (
  select
   0 as level,
   id, parentid, name 
  from path
  where id = 5 -- this would be filled in later
  union all
  select
   child.level + 1 as level,
   parent.id, parent.parentid, parent.name
  from _rpath child
  join path parent on child.parentid = parent.id
) , c AS (
  select
    rp, d, d.status
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.pathid ORDER BY d.creation DESC) AS rn
  from data d
  join _rpath rp
  on rp.id = d.pathid
  ), datapaths AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM c
  WHERE rn =1
    AND status != 'deleted'
    )
      select dp.rp, dp.d
  from datapaths dp
  left join datapaths dpNext
  on (dpNext.rp).level < (dp.rp).level or
    ((dpNext.rp).level = (dp.rp).level 
    and (dpNext.d).creation > (dp.d).creation)
  where (dpNext.d).id is null;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7b4d27e2f8282fe9b68316d7985346c0)**

How it works:

```
-- calculate node number for each pathid sort by creation descending
-- newest one gets always 1
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.pathid ORDER BY d.creation DESC) 

-- get only first for each pathid but omit if it is 'deleted'
WHERE rn =1
  AND status != 'deleted'
```